# Actually "calculate" the color at a point along a CAGradientLayer?

Tags: ios, cagradientlayer, cgcolor

Here's an interesting thing, say you have the usual ...

```
var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
func setup() {

 C = some complicated array of CGColors
 L = some complicated array of NSNumber (mono' increasing)

 gradientLayer.colors = C
 gradientLayer.locations = L

 gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
 gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)

 layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

---

**Note** of course the .locations array (and the matching colors one) can have tens or hundreds of entries, the heart of the problem.

---

OK - iOS will perfectly render the gradient, swirling through various colors.

Now say I then ask **"at the point 0.3437, what is the color" ?**

How does one get that?

Does `CAGradientLayer` have a way to spit it out?

Conversely (without using CAGradientLayer), is there a way to calculate the interpolation in C and L ?

(PS, yes, I'm aware you could read the pixel color from the rendering; not the question here.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `CAGradientLayer` has an option to give you the color at a certain point.

In order to interpolate the color, you can do the following:

```
    let point: CGFloat = 0.3437

    let startPoint = gradientLayer.startPoint
    let endPoint = gradientLayer.endPoint

    let x = (endPoint.x - point) / (endPoint.x - startPoint.x)

    if let start = gradientLayer.colors?.first,
        let end = gradientLayer.colors?.last {

        let startColorCGColor = start as! CGColor
        let endColorCGColor = end as! CGColor

        let startColor = UIColor(cgColor: startColorCGColor)
        let endColor = UIColor(cgColor: endColorCGColor)

        var startR: CGFloat = 0
        var startG: CGFloat = 0
        var startB: CGFloat = 0
        var endR: CGFloat = 0
        var endG: CGFloat = 0
        var endB: CGFloat = 0
        startColor.getRed(&startR, green: &startG, blue: &startB, alpha: nil)
        endColor.getRed(&endR, green: &endG, blue: &endB, alpha: nil)

        let r,g,b: CGFloat

        if x <= 0 {
            r = startR
            g = startG
            b = startB
        } else if x >= 1 {
            r = endR
            g = endG
            b = endB
        } else {
            r = x * startR + (1.0 - x) * endR
            g = x * startG + (1.0 - x) * endG
            b = x * startB + (1.0 - x) * endB
        }

        print("R,G,B = \(r),\(g),\(b)") // This is the result.
    }
```

But this code only works for your code, because the start and end points have both the same `y` values.

Comment: Ah!  that was quite a waste of your time, Tawa - sorry.  The .startPoint, .endPoint are nothing, the problem is, imagine the dozens of points in the .locations array!!!

Comment: @Fattie it's fine. You can always update the algorithm to let it accept multiple points. Otherwise I think your only bet would be to get the pixel like you mentioned in your question.